# Queries on array values on Parse.com isn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, parse-platform, pfquery

This is basically killing my app and Parse isn't exactly being prompt with their responses.
Queries on pointer arrays aint working.

Try this in your app:

```
- (void)runTest{
   // Run a build to store 20 rows.
   for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
       NSMutableArray *recipients = [NSMutableArray array];
       [recipients addObject:[PFUser currentUser]];
       PFObject *message = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Run"];
       [message addObjectsFromArray:recipients forKey:@"recipients"];
       [message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

       }];
   }
}

- (void)runTestQuery{
   // Run a second build to query the 20 rows. Not all 20 are returned.

   PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Run"];
   [query whereKey:@"recipients" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
   [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"Objects count: %li",(long)objects.count);
   }];
```

}

Comment: It looks like you are declaring the array 20 times and then adding the current user to each array. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Jacob - this is just a simple test to create 20 rows for purposes of demonstrating this bug.

Comment: Can you confirm that it is 20 rows? It looks like you're creating a new array each time you run the loop.

Comment: Yes, it's confirmed 20 rows. I found the bug, now I have to wait for them to fix it. See my last comment on this bug report, here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1539962162890555/

Comment: @jacob, I'm intentionally creating a new array - I'm creating 20 records (objects) where each record (object) has it's own recipients attribute of type array. Hence why I create the array 20 times.